# Delphi: TTask seem slow only the first time

Tags: delphi

On button click i create 3 task each with empty procedure and write into a console the time difference from the method call and the tasks list complete:

```
procedure TWinTest.BtnThreadTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  aTasks: array of ITask;
  aStart: Cardinal;
begin
  aStart := GetTickCount;

  Setlength(aTasks, 3);

  aTasks[0] := TTask.Create(procedure() begin

  end);
  aTasks[0].Start;

  aTasks[1] := TTask.Create(procedure() begin

  end);
  aTasks[1].Start;

  aTasks[2] := TTask.Create(procedure() begin

  end);
  aTasks[2].Start;

  TTask.WaitForAll(aTasks);


  Writeln( GetTickCount - aStart, 'ms');
end;
```

The first call take 31 ms, the successive call take 0 ms.

[image]

Why the first call is slower than the successive? maybe delphi cache the thread and reuse it on the successive call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, task threads are cached (in a thread pool) by default. This is documented behavior:

[Tutorial: Using Tasks from the Parallel Programming Library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tutorial:_Using_Tasks_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library)

> This tutorial shows how to implement an application using [tasks](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask) from the Parallel Programming Library (PPL). [Tasks](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask) are units of work that are in a queue and start when the CPU time is available. [Tasks](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask) can run operations in parallel. **There is a master thread that manages this queue and allocates threads from the [thread-pool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TThreadPool) to do work of the tasks. This [thread-pool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TThreadPool) has a number of threads that depends on the number of CPUs that are available.**

You can customize the behavior of the pooling by creating a [`TThreadPool`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TThreadPool) object and pass it to the [`TTask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask) constructor:

> If desired, Create can also be given a parameter of [TThreadPool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TThreadPool) from which the instance of [TTask](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask) may draw the thread resources it needs. Without specifying an instance of [TThreadPool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TThreadPool), resources are drawn from a default based upon the CPU and threading capabilities of the platform.